# How to manipulate different charts by angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, chart.js

I have problem with multiple charts using angular to dynamically create them.

HTML:

```
.
.
<body>
<div>
    <div>
        <div ng-app="app">
            <div ng-controller="barCtrl">
                <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar ng-isolate-scope"
                    chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series">
                </canvas>
            </div>
            <div ng-controller = "lineCtrl">
                <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line ng-isolate-scope"
                    chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series">
                </canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]).controller("lineCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    var jsondata = [];
    var jsonLabel = [];
    $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            var j = response.data[i].Not_fully_compliant;
            var k = response.data[i].Policy;
            count += 1;
            jsondata.push(j);
            jsonLabel.push(count);
        }
    });

    $scope.labels = jsonLabel;
    $scope.series = ['JSON object'];
    $scope.data = [
        jsondata
    ];
});

angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]).controller("barCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    var jsondata = [];
    var jsonLabel = [];
    $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            var j = response.data[i].Not_fully_compliant;
            var k = response.data[i].Policy;
            count += 1;
            jsondata.push(j);
            jsonLabel.push(count);
        }
    });

    $scope.labels = jsonLabel;
    $scope.series = ['JSON object'];
    $scope.data = [
        jsondata
    ];
});
```

I was trying to manipulate it by ng-controller, but it doesn't work. 
I was trying to give different ng-app="names" to select the part of t he code dynamically by the script.

What script does: Connect to the page where JSON object has been generated, pulls out the information and put it into the chart. I was trying to find any useful on the web, but I couldn't find any correct answer showing multiple charts.

I was using this tutorial to create charts: http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/
. However after inspecting the page and trying to solve how the guy is able to manipulate different charts in the same angular app it still doesn't work.

Error:

[image: This is the error output from the console]

Please notice that I didn't put my whole HTML code here, although I presented how it looks like.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: is that possible to create a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have to declare the module again, use the same module with two different controllers,

```
angular.module("app").controller("barCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
}
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/PyUqZ5n2ZbXpj18VkMmE?p=preview)**

Comment: How it is possible to use different controllers? Is it possible to do it like that: .controller("1","2",Function( ) { }

Comment: @Maltesse check the demo

Comment: Thank you. Didn't see the demo when I was posting comment. It works perfectly. Can you shortly describe why it wasn't working before?

Comment: You are trying to declare the same module with this syntax  angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]) which would result in that error

Comment: So the 3rd chart, which will be the next one can be created the same way like the 2nd one with different controller :)